# bash - find command with regex user option

Tags: bash

I need get all files from directory with `-user` option (owner), but user must by in regexp like `user_*`. This option (regexp) is for filenames but i search solution for user. Sorry for my English.

For example - users (file owners): userA, userB, user_1, user_2... etc

A solution like this:

```
find ./ -type f -user "user_*"
```

except the above doesn't work.

Comment: Your exampes are not consistent. Shoold there be an underscore after `user`, or not? Also, your pattern looks like a glob, not a regex.

Comment: Yes, You have right, but I thought about similar solutions... regexp or glob.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53720032/6770384). However users do not have to be listed manually anymore.

`compgen -u` lists all users. `compgen -u user_` lists all users starting with `user_`. If you want more flexibility use `compgen -u | grep regex`.

```
find . -type f \( printf -- '-user %s -o ' $(compgen -u user_) false \)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-o`r to compose predicates :

```
find ./ -type f \( -user user1 -o -user user2 -o -user user3 \)
```

It won't be possible to use wildcards that would select over users, but you could possibly generate the command from more specific wildcards :

```
find . -type f \( $(printf -- '-user user_%s -o ' {1,2,A,B}) false \)
```

Comment: The final `-o true` will select all files, won't it?

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is good solution for small number users but helpfull ;)

Comment: @PiotrSiewiera under which form are you getting your users? E.g. is it a fixed list you'll hardcode in your script, or do you read it from somewhere at runtime? I'm sure I could use a solution akin to my second command to generate the appropriate `find` command

Comment: @Aaron Good idea... but i get 'paths must precede expression: false'. I will write this in script, but now I test in runtime :)

Comment: Weird, the `printf` is supposed to expand into `-user user_1 -o [...] -o` with an extra trailing `-o` which is the reason why I added the `false`. You could use `set -x` (or simply prepend the command with `echo`) to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct support for this. Either generate the command from a list of user names, or postprocess the output from `find`.

Supposing you have GNU `find`, try

```
find . -type f -printf '%u\t%p\n' |
grep '^user_' |
cut -f1
```

This will fail if you have file names with newlines, or if you don't have GNU `find`. You could probably get around these limitations easily; for replacing the GNU extenstion `-printf`, try `-exec stat` though the exact options to pass in are platform-dependent.

Comment: Thanks, this is good solution for utf-8 encoding, but when files are in windows-1250 and linux see brusches ;) that cut out from result this files (with brusches :). Thanks for help

Comment: I don't understand "brusches". You can convert the result to UTF-8 by piping to `iconv -f cp1250`. This is unrelated to anything you mentioned in your question, and would affect any one of the answers here. Maybe think about converting the file system to this millennium.

Comment: Users put files like doc, xls (ftp), and this files come from Windows  system and are encode in windows-1250 with polish language ą,ę,ś,ć etc Linux see this file name like 'someth?ing? .xls'. Your command work for me but it cut off files with '?' characters in result. Grep command cut off this records.

Comment: Do the `iconv` before the `grep` then.